# Homology of connected manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $[z]_x$ be the image of $[z]\in H_n(M;R)$ in $H_n(M;M-x;R)$. Then how can I show that if M is a connected manifold, $[z]_x$ is either 0 for all $x$ or nonzero for all $x$?

This is from one line from Prop 3.29 of Hatcher's book. I guess the point is to prove the set where $[z]_x$ vanishes is both closed and open, but I have no idea to do this. Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Is $R$ the real numbers?

Comment: @AviSteiner  Some coefficient ring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M$ is connected manifold, then for arbitrary $x,y\in M$ exists a diffeomorphism $f:M\to M$, such that $f(x)=y$ and $f$ is isotopic to identity. Now, concider the diagram
$$
\begin{array}
H &H_*(M) & \stackrel{f_*}{\longrightarrow} & H_*(M) \\
&\downarrow{} & & \downarrow{} \\
H_*(M,\hspace{-3mm}&M-x) & \stackrel{f_*}{\longrightarrow} & H_*(M,M-y)  
\end{array}
$$
Here $f_*$ in the top row is identyty homomorphism, directly from homotopy invariance, so we have the desired statement.

Comment: Wow, I do not know the existence of such diffeomorphism before. But in the text I believe it is a little bit more general. I mean the manifold is not assumed to be smooth. In this case does there exist similar result? Some homeomorphism that homotopic to identity?

Comment: @Learning, of course it will be true when for each pair of points $x,y\in M$ there exists open $U\ni x,y$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. for such $U$ you may take neighborhood of a path connecting $x$ with $y$